# Save and read files in isolated storage

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I try to save files in IsoStore. In WP8 emulator files have been successfully saved, but when I run my program in other emulators or on my phone(with WP7.8) I get a error: "path must be a valid file name" 
I do this:

```
                         var path = @"\Shared\Media\mapp\";
                         var imageName = guid from the server;

                            if (!_fileStorage.DirectoryExists(path))
                                _fileStorage.CreateDirectory(path);

//here I get a error      using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream =
                                _fileStorage.OpenFile(path + imageName,
                                                      FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                            {//do anything}
```

I try to set path = @"iso:\Shared\Media\mapp\" or @"isostore:\Shared\Media\mapp\" or @"files:\Shared\Media\mapp\" or @"file:\Shared\Media\mapp\" and it doesn't work.
If I set @"\Shared\Media\" all fine in all devices. Who can tell me why I can't create a directory?

Comment: this link may help you http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage-read-and-save-text-files

Comment: Actually, you've written that: "If I set `@"\Shared\Media\"` all fine in all devices.", and that seems strange for me, as it will also fail at WP7 device(tried it right now). Are you sure?

Comment: Yes, with @"\Shared\Media\" works fine both WP7.1 and WP7.8 emulators and on phones with OS 7.5 and 7.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Windows-Phone-7 you can't create a directory, which name ends with "/" or "//", that will cause an "path must be a valid file name" error.

To solve your problem, just change your code a bit:

```
            var path = @"\Shared\Media\mapp";
            var imageName = guid from the server;

            using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                if (!store.FileExists(path))
                {
                    store.CreateDirectory(path);
                }
                store.OpenFile(path + "\\" + imageName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            }
```

Hope, that helps.

Comment: Your method works just as well as it works without creating a own directory =) Thanks a lot for your answer.